# GUI noob - no prior experience with Qt or Rqt

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, rqt, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- **Problem Statement:**

I have a USB camera stream and I can view these images multiple ways.
But now, I have to create a **GUI with say an image window** that is streaming these images on a node "Listener.py" and has some control options available to the user.

- **Example Scenario:**

[image: image description]

I can see three buttons, and I need to do this :

```
   onClick(Button1): Display Image1 on ImageWindow
   onClick(Button2): Display Image2 on ImageWindow
   onClick(Button3): Display Image3 on ImageWindow
```

How do I go about creating this GUI?
I don't need an exclusive code, but any/all links to **well-documented tutorials** is terribly appreciated.
I actually went over to rqt/tutorials page but found it a little overwhelming.

Posting here in the hope that I get out of noob status and other noobs can benefit from constructive answers as well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207718/gui-noob---no-prior-experience-with-qt-or-rqt/) by [voladoddi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19646/voladoddi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2015-04-23

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [voladoddi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19646/voladoddi/) on 2015-04-24**:
No takers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to use `image_transport` for your video data you must use  C++ since there is no equivalent in Python at the moment.

You can create your own rqt plugin by following the tutorials and looking at the code of other plugins. If the existing documentation for that seems to be too overwhelming you might want to start with some beginner tutorials on ROS before.

For your specific goal it would make sense to reuse some of the code of the [rqt_image_view](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/tree/groovy-devel/rqt_image_view) plugin.

**Update:**

`rqt` is built on the gui toolkit `Qt`. You will find a lot of documentation about Qt itself which is not covered in the ROS wiki:

- Qt widgets: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/widgets-tutorial.html
- Qt signals & slots: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html
- Qt threads: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html
- Threading in general: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [voladoddi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19646/voladoddi/) on 2015-04-24**:
Hi @dirk-thomas, my problem is not in understanding ROS, but the UI part of it.
http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Python%20Plugin

for example, mentions several terms like "widgets", "signals/slots", "threads" that do not as of yet make sense to me.

**Comment by [voladoddi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19646/voladoddi/) on 2015-04-24**:
However, thanks for the rqt_image_view plugin link. Maybe I should use the existing plugin, modify a few things there and then visualize how they look.